# Как сделать горизонтальную прокрутку для блока с контентом, если контент - фоновое изображение

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Как сделать горизонтальную прокрутку для блока с контентом, если контент - фоновое изображение.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.block {
  width: 120px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
}

.text{
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="text">
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<p>
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @get_it_skill как это удалите ? она ответила на ваш вопрос а то что вы в прыжке переобулись - ваши трудности . Потом вы на лету опять переобуетесь ..и так будете изобретать 1000 вариантов